# setOnPreferenceClickListener function doesn't work for Preference on Android

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I'm using the code below to print text to logcat, but the `setOnPreferenceClickListener` function doesn't catch the event.

I'm using Android API Level 8 to test the code.

```xml
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="settings_use_cache"
        android:summary="Use cache"
        android:title="Use Cache" />

    <Preference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="settings_delete_cache"
        android:summary="Delete all cache data"
        android:title="Clear Cache" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the code

```java
public static class CachePreferenceFragment extends
        PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.w("DBG", "Oncreate started");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_cache);

        Preference settings_delete_cache=findPreference("settings_delete_cache");
        settings_delete_cache.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Log.w("Prefence", "Deleting Cache");
                return false;
            }
        });         
    }
}
```

What can I do to ensure the listener catches the event?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the onCreate. But I do find it unusual that your CachePreferenceFragment is static class o.O The only other things is that your logs settings might not be set to see warning. Do you see "Log.w("DBG", "Oncreate started");" in the logs?

Comment: Yes, I see "Oncreate started" text in the logs. Logging works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
After talking with this dev outside of the thread, it was identified that the problem was that he was putting his listener inside of the fragment. So this code actually works, but it will only run if you are using a two-panel layout. In fact this is stated right above the method:

```
    /**
     * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */

    public static class CachePreferenceFragment extends
            PreferenceActivity {
```

The solution is to also set the onPreferenceClick listener in setupSimplePreferencesScreen()!

Comment: I have checked the link before I wrote the post. This solution doesn't work too. I have done a copy-paste but result still the same.

Comment: No it didn't worked again, here is the code that I wrote : [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/afNfiLTA)

Comment: Both removing defaultValue and using CheckBoxPreference didn't do any sense.

Comment: Yah sorry, I've done this exact thing dozens of times and never had any problems. I would try cleaning your project, restarting computer, restarting phone, etc. If you send me the project I can see if I have any luck with it, otherwise goodluck